# To Print array of numbers into a string

Tags: c

I have an input as a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5)}
My output should be b = 12345

I tried with the following program, but i got struct up in traversing along the Char Pointer , can anyone give me the proper solution for my code..

Attached the sample code,

```
int main()

{
   int a[5] ={1,2,3,4,5};
   int i ; 
   char *b; 


   for(i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
   {   
      sprintf(b,"%d",a[i]);
      b= b+1;
   }   

   printf("\n %s",b);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 C or C++? Select a language, because they are very different languages

Comment: Right now you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code. Where does `b` point? And after you modify it (with `b = b + 1` (which is the same as `b++`)) where do you think it will point?

Comment: I want the sample code to be executed in C

Answer (score 1):

The straight forward approach is simply:

```
#include <ansi_c.h>//collection of all ansi C headers files in my environment.  
                   //replace this with appropriate headers supporting your environment
int main()
#define MAX_DIGIT_LEN 10 //memory allocation for char *b

{
   int a[5] ={1,2,3,4,5};
   int i ; 
   char *b; //in your original post, you never set 
            //this pointer to point to any space
            //it was therefore an uninitialized 
            //pointer, with no memory space.  

   //you must initialize pointers, and allocate some memory.
   //Somthing like this will work:   

   //memory must be MAX_DIGIT_LEN * number of ints in array 
   b = malloc(MAX_DIGIT_LEN*(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))+1);//using "sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]" 
                                        //will accommodate array size changes 
                                        //+1 allows for NULL byte at end of char array
   sprintf(b, "%d%d%d%d%d", a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]);    
   printf("\n %s",b);
   free(b);

   return 0;
}
```

***Produces this output:***
[image]

***If you want to use a loop***, then consider using (creating) an additional variable:

```
#include <ansi_c.h>//collection of all ansi C headers files in my environment.  
                   //replace this with appropriate headers supporting your environment

#define MAX_DIGIT_LEN 10 //memory allocation for char *b
int main()  
{
   int a[5] ={1,2,3,4,5};
   int i ; 
   char *b;
   char buf[MAX_DIGIT_LEN];
               //create this as an intermediary place 
               //to store discrete elements of a[]
               //arbitrarily chose 10, to hold up to 
               //9 digit integer, such as 123456789.
               //if you anticipate larger digits, 
               //use a bigger index to create buf[] 

   //memory must be MAX_DIGIT_LEN * number of ints in array 
   b = calloc(MAX_DIGIT_LEN*(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))+1, 1);
                                           //note calloc (rather than malloc) is 
                                           //preferable here to initialize
                                           //all memory space with 0 before
                                           //attempting strcat() calls.

   for(i=0 ; i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) ; i++)
   {   
       sprintf(buf, "%d", a[i]);
       strcat(b,buf);
   }      
   printf("\n %s",b);
   free(b);

   return 0;
}
```

***Produces this output:***
[image]

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
   int a[5] ={13,425,563,67477,685};
   int i ; 
   int len = 0;
   char b[10] = ""; 
   char *pb = b;

   for(i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
   {   
      len = strlen(pb);
      pb+= len;
      sprintf(pb,"%d",a[i]);
   }   

   printf("\n %s",b);
   
   return 0;
}

Comment: See my response to this same comment under other post.  I am not sure why you posted it.  It does not work.  ***what is your question***?

Comment: +1 for a scale-able approach.  Note: to scale `MAX_DIGIT_LEN` for all `int`, could use `#define MAX_DIGIT_LEN (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3+3)`

Comment: @chux - Thanks.  Is CHAR_BIT normally pre-defined?.

Comment: Yes, `CHAR_BIT` is in `<limits.h>` an maybe via other .h.  It is _almost_ always 8.  Depends on how portable your want.

Comment: @chux - Answered my own question, (limits.h)  :)  That is a great suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Lol.  It is the _ansi_c_ _collection_ in my environment for all ansi C headers, such as assert.h, ctype.h, errno.h, ... and several more.  I do not often see _heck_ used anymore.  It actually made me laugh, and for that, I thank you.  ( BTW, I will edit my answer to make this clear to OP)

Comment: @ryyker: It's my "hell" substitute when I'm trying to be polite ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the destination correctly:

```
int main()
{
   int a[5] ={1,2,3,4,5};
   int i ; 
   char b[6] = ""; 
   char *pb = b;

   for(i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
   {   
      sprintf(pb,"%d",a[i]);
      pb++;
   }   

   printf("\n %s",b);

   return 0;
}
```

---

or without sprintf

```
int main()
{
   int a[5] ={1,2,3,4,5};
   int i ; 
   char b[6] = ""; 
   for(i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
   {   
      b[i] = a[i]+48; //Conversion to ASCII
   }   

   printf("\n %s",b);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: can u explain me the same

Comment: There's no trailing '\0' in `b`, printf could make the whole thing crash.

Comment: b is a stack variable and bp points to it, use b[6], so its terminated

Comment: @unda sprintf makes a '\0' at the end, which leads to UB because b is too small.

Comment: @unda by using the ascii table, 0 starts at 48.

Comment: The second code will not give me the expected result while giving random input, such that a = {12,23,46,57,89}

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
   int a[5] ={13,425,563,67477,685};
   int i ; 
   int len = 0;
   char b[10] = ""; 
   char *pb = b;

   for(i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
   {   
      len = strlen(pb);
      pb+= len;
      sprintf(pb,"%d",a[i]);
   }   

   printf("\n %s",b);
   
   return 0;
}

Comment: @Udhay - Not sure why you posted the code in that comment.  It does not work.  `pb` is not initialized such that it can hold even the first assignment:  `sprintf(pb, "%d", a[i]);.  Its the same thing people have been saying for the last hour:  ***if using pointers, then initialize them to have space before using.***

Comment: @ryyker : I cant get u, but for the same code i got my result

Comment: @Udhay - Not without edits.  The code you posted in the comment does not run without errors, and does not produce expected results.  Especially with the input array digit sizes (i.e. 67477), your output will only be "13425563" before you overrun your buffer.

Comment: @Udhay: My comment was for Eun. And his solution works as long as array `a` contains only *digits* (number from `0` to `9`). I suggest you to take better example to avoid answers which don't fit completely with your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your for loop (moving with the pointer)

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
{   
   sprintf(&b[i], "%d", a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int a[5] ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int i;
    char *b;
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);
    size_t len = 0;

    for(i=0 ; i<n ; ++i){
        len += snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", a[i]);
    }
    b = malloc(len + 1);
    len = 0;
    for(i=0 ; i<n ; ++i){
        len += sprintf(b + len, "%d", a[i]);
    }

    printf("\n%s\n", b);
    free(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i, a[5] ={1,2,3,4,5};
   char buff[sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) + 1] = {0};
   char *b = buff;

   for(i=0 ; i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) ; i++)
   {   
      sprintf(b++,"%d",a[i]);
   }   
   printf("%s\n", buff);
   return 0;
}
```

Your code needs to make sure to do the following:

-- Create a place to store your string of numbers. This is done like so:

```
char buff[sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) + 1] = {0};
```

Notice a few things.

a. You can calculate the number of ints in your `a` array by dividing the total size of the array by the size of one of it's elements. You need make sure your buffer has space for the NULL at the end so add 1.

b. You want to initialize the buffers values. By assigning this buffer to {0} you will end up with a buffer where all elements are set to 0 ( NULL ). This guarantees our buffer has a NULL at the end which is needed so printf() knows how many bytes to print. Even though [sprintf()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm) adds a NULL at the end of the string it's a good idea to get into the habit of properly initializing your buffers and variables.

-- You need to make sure `b` is pointing to your buffer. You do it like this:

```
char *b = buff;
```

Because buff is an array `buff` is the address of the first element.

-- And finally in your for loop, it's good form to once again calculate the number of elements in your array that you are iterating over so that you don't have to remember to change the loop if you change the size of your int array.